# Can we use solr indexing to search and query any data from a web page or sharepoint site?

Tags: indexing, solr, web-crawler

Can we use solr indexing to search and query any data from a web page or sharepoint site? And how much does the license cost?

Comment: Solr is free, open source software under the Apache License - so [download it and try it out to see if it fits your use case](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/downloads.html). You'll have to be more specific about your requirements to say if its a good fit. There's a commercial version of Solr named [Lucidworks Fusion that has a set of Sharepoint connectors](https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion/2.0/Connectors_and_Datasources_Reference/SharePoint-Connector-and-Datasource-Configuration.html), easily allowing content from Sharepoint to be indexed.

Comment: Thank You Mats! My requirement would be as follows: I have certain websites like sharepoint, Wikipedia, and any internal sites where I would like to search and query the data using solr indexing. So is it possible?

Comment: You probably want to use something like Nutch in that case, as that's more of a spider solution. It can still use Solr as a backend for searching, but Nutch gathers data and pushes it into the index.

Comment: Thank You Mats! I just came across Apache Nutch and heard the same from you as well :)